# Using AsyncTask to call another application

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to use AsyncTask to call another application. I have a main app that does its own thing but when I launch it, it does an AsyncTask to call a "messages" application which checks to see if there are any unread messages and then displays a notification in the status bar.

However, when I called execute(), the messages application jumps to the front and I have to press the back button to get to my main application.

Code is as follows (my main application)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MessageUpdate update = new MessageUpdate(this);
    System.out.println("Calling Update");
    update.execute(null);
....
```

My AsyncTask:

```
public class MessageUpdate extends AsyncTask{

    Context ctx;
    public MessageUpdate(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        notificationIntent.setClassName("com.test.messages", "com.test.messages.MessageCheck");
        ctx.startActivity(notificationIntent);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell my why the MessagesCheck jumps to the front and how to stop it? Or if what I'm doing is even feasible?

Comment: you probably want to use AsyncTask in your MessageCheck activity.Because it seems to me that lengthy work is done there

Comment: Did you write MessagesCheck yourself?

Comment: Why would you start an activity from a background thread? Premature optimization. D. Knuth will be very mad at you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, a service is the way to go. However, if you use [bindService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) the service will only last as long as it's bound.

Just to clarify some of the issues:

- Using `startActivity` to communicate with a background task is not what you want, as an Activity is a user interface component, which will come to the front when activated.
- The suggestion is that you add a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) to your "messages" application, *not* the main application.
- You can then communicate with the "messages" application from the main application by binding to the service. If you do this (using bindService), the service will not run indefinitely.
- The details of how to do this are [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).

You could do all this without an AsyncTask, however it may help to avoid blocking the UI thread *if* the service takes significant time to do its job. Alternatively, your service could use a background thread of its own to check for messages and post the notification.

Comment: Glad to hear that. BTW, if all your service is going to do is post a notification, you might like to check out [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). I haven't used it, but looks like a simple model.

Comment: It first checks against a server if there are any messages, then posts the notification.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment wasn't clear. If all your service does _in terms of communicating the result_ is post a notification, IntentService might provide a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered make com.test.messages.MessageCheck a Service not an Activity, then calling startService(...)

Comment: MessageCheck is a whole other application that I would like to call. And from what I've read, doesn't service run indefinitely? I would just like to call my Messages application, have it notify the user if there is any unread messages and that's that.

Comment: In which case it doesn't do what you want, you're launching MessageCheck. If you try and have an Activity in the background then it will be paused. You need a service if you want it to execute in the background.

Comment: So I gave it a try, I turned it from an AsyncTask to a Service. But the same thing happens where my Messages application jumps to the foreground. Am I still doing something wrong? I took everything in the `doInBackground` and stuck it in the service's `onCreate` method.

Comment: That wasn't that point. MessageCheck is an Activity and will launch to the foreground, it doesn't do what you want. You need a version of MessageCheck that runs as a service.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting an Activity in your ASyncTask, so your current Activity is brought to the back.

In order to prevent that, you'll have to use a different way to check if there is a new message. You could either do that verification in your ASyncTask and display the notification from it, or use a Service.